# ElasticSearch: delete where _type contains

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi I would like to delete all indexes belongings to a particular type, but I have this error

> [illegal_argument_exception] request [/datastorage] contains
>   unrecognized parameter: [type]

```
deleteAllItems: function (type,callback) {
        console.log(type)
        client.indices.delete({
            index: 'datastorage',
            type : 'cliente_1',
            body: {
                query: {
                        "match_all": {} 
                }
            }
        }, function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err.message);
            }
            callback();
        });

    }
```

Thanks
Andrea

Comment: which ES version u using and can you try doing this using `curl` or any rest client?

Comment: I am using the last version

Comment: In the last version there are no types anymore, it was deprecated. Try to remove that parameter.

Comment: but i need it :-) i want to delete items where type is 'client_1'

Comment: @Gelso77 , how did you create your index with `type` in latest version?